# During "printing" the elements of linked list. "(code1)" is printing all elements while "(code2)" is printing elements accept "FIRST" element?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

LANGUAGE USED - C Language
COMPILER - GCC
PROBLEM -   During "printing" the elements of linked list. "(code1)" is printing all elements while "(code2)" is printing elements accept "FIRST" element,why ?

**WORKING CODE1 :  ---**

```
`void print()
 {
struct node *temp = head;
printf("List is :");
while(temp!=NULL)   **PRINTING FIRST ELEMENT**
{
printf("%d",temp->data);
temp=temp->next;
}
printf("\n");
}`
```

**NON WORKING CODE2  : ---**

```
void print()
{
struct node *temp = head;
printf("List is :");
while(temp->next!=NULL)   **NOT PRINTING FIRST ELEMENT**   
{
printf("%d",temp->data);
temp=temp->next;
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about not printing first element? It should not be printing last element.

Comment: Why would you expect `temp -> next != NULL` and `temp != NULL` to be the same? Draw the linked list on a piece of paper and check the loop conditions and try to see where it goes. You'll then notice why it's the second snippet does not print the _last_ element (not first)